# How to retrive deleted contact and call log from iPhone Programatically

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, contacts, phone-call

Can any one help me to retrive deleted contact and deleted phone calls from iPhone
Programatically.

Thanks,
Swapnil

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it possible. First of all, because they're not kept locally, and the only way to restore them for the end user is to use a device backup. See [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205018).

The only way you could probably achieve this is to track contacts and calls lists and compare them with new values. This, of course, won't help with contacts that were both added and deleted between app launches.